# Excel 2007 Calculations

Tags: excel-2007

I have a Excel sheet, one date column with different description and values. How can I calculate the sum of the values for each dates using formula not pivot table?

[image: Excel Calculation Details attached]

I need summary as shown below:

```
Date   Jun-15  Jul-15
 1     175.00  200.00 
 2     100.00   75.00 
 3     200.00  175.00 
 4      60.00   70.00 
 5      20.00  225.00 
 6      80.00   50.00
```

Comment: Can you show your excel looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple *SUMIF()* formula:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. it is perfect and I am very happy.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this to solve your problem. Please let me know it this resolves your query.

[image]